# How to define a nested object within model? (angular2/typescript)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-http

I'm playing around with Angular2, and was hoping someone could offer some advice on how to achieve this;

For example, if my model currently looks like this for an employee:

```
export class Employee {
    constructor(
        public firstName: string,
        public lastName: string,
        public email: string,
        public days: string,
        public hours: string, 
    ){}
}
```

and I want to to place days/hour into their own object, how could that be achieved?

(i.e like..)

```
public availability: {
        public days: string,
        public hours: string
},
```

and then would the http get request stay the same like below?

```
getEmployees() {
      return this.http.get('...')
             .map((response: Response) => {
                 const data = response.json().obj;
                 let objs: any[] = [];

                 for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                     let employee = new Employee(
                     data[i].firstName,
                     data[i].lastName, 
                     data[i].email, 
                     data[i].availability.days,
                     data[i].availability.hours
                     );

                     objs.push(employee)
                 }
                 return objs
             })
          }
```

Just to clarify, I would like my get request to return something like;

```
var obj = {
    firstName: "test",
    lastName: "test",
    email: "test",
    availability: {
      days: "test",
      hours: "test"
    }
  }
```

Hope someone can help out! I'm tried to look around, but haven't come across anything that can help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Something like this

```
export class Employee {
    constructor(
        public firstName: string,
        public lastName: string,
        public email: string,
        public availability: Availability // refer to type Availability  below
    ){}
}

export class Availability {
    constructor(
        public days: string,
        public hours: string
    ){}
}
```

Http get request should stay the same, then change on how you create new instance of employee

```
let employee = new Employee(
    data[i].firstName,
    data[i].lastName,
    data[i].email,
    new Availability(
          data[i].availability.days,
          data[i].availability.hours
    )
);
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting errors using this example - `Cannot find name 'Availability'.` is what appears in the service, and in the class file - `';' expected`. I think the `export class Availability` won't be visible inside the Employee class unless you import it?

Comment: @confusedandenthused yeah sorry, the `Availability` class should have its constructor, I have fixed it, then import `Availability ` class in the `Employee` class and in your service.

Comment: Thanks - that got it working! Also worth noting that you have to import the new class into the component to get it to work.

Comment: what if the `model` has one hundred property? you can't do it like this.

Comment: You need to define interfaces instead of classes to work properly.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I did ( for `Ionic` project ) something like

```
export class Availability {
    days: string  = "";
    hours: string = "";
}

export class Employee {
    firstName: string = "";
    lastName:  string = "";
    email:     string = "";

    availability = new Availability()
}
```

So if I use these models in a `<form>` I receive an empty structure of this `Employee` class.

It also work when I declare variables like `employeeObservable : Observable<Employee[]>;` when I query a firebase DB for example ...

Answer (score 2):

For anyone showing up to this a couple years later, there's a helpful library that can help with this called class-transformer.

Using this library has been the easiest: https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer

```
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';

export class Employee {
    firstName: string;
    email: string;
    days: string;
    hours: string;

    @Type(() => Availability)
    availablity: Availablity

    constructor(args: Employee) {
      Object.assign(this, args);
    }
}

export class Availability {
    days: string;
    hours: string;

    constructor(args: Availability) {
      Object.assign(this, args);
    }
}
```

A few things changed:

1. The use of the `@Type` decorator comes from the class-transformer module. This allows you to transform nested objects. Here is the documentation: https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#working-with-nested-objects
2. We've added a `constructor` which allows you to create instances of these Classes and pass through attributes to them of their own respective types. Take a look at this post [Converting httpClient answer to model objects [Angular 6]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50551649/converting-httpclient-answer-to-model-objects-angular-6) as it shines more light onto whats happening here.

Then within your service this is how your code changes:

```
import { plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';
import { Employee } from './Employee'

getEmployees() {
  return this.http.get('...')
    .map((response: Response) => plainToClass(Employee, response.json().obj as Employee[]))
```

`plainToClass` will take the raw JSON response and transform it into instances of your Employee Class. If you console.log out the result of `getEmployees()` you will see that it returns an Array of Employees that each have an attribute called `availability` of type Availability.