# Converting httpClient answer to model objects [Angular 6]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have a question about the Angular 5 httpClient.

**This is a model class with a method foo() I'd like to receive from the server**

```
export class MyClass implements Deserializable{
  id: number;
  title: string;

  deserialize(input: any) {
    Object.assign(this, input);
    return this;
  }

  foo(): string {
    // return "some string conversion" with this.title
  }
}
```

This is my service requesting it:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { MyClass } from './MyClass';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyClassService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getMyStuff(): Observable<MyClass[]> {
    // this is where I hope to convert the json to instances of MyClass
    return this.http.get<MyClass[]>('api/stuff')
  }
}
```

## My Problem

When I ask the service for instances of `MyClass` I get the data, but I cannot run `{{ item.foo() }}` in the template. Also, when I `console.log()` the `typeof` of an item where it is received in the service, I **do no see** instances of an object of `MyClass`.

**What am I doing wrong?** I thought that writing `this.http.get<MyClass[]>('api/stuff')` would do the conversion.

Any hints? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have a read of this to understand how to use Deserializable in your model with data from an API. https://nehalist.io/working-with-models-in-angular/

Comment: Similar question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47499324/angular-5-models-httpclient-type-casting

Comment: similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63964124/angular-convert-api-data-into-new-data-type-in-reusable-clean-method

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When doing that, TypeScript only does "type assertion". It means that you're telling TypeScript that your object is of type `MyClass`, but the object isn't actually an instance of `MyClass` at runtime. In order to call functions defined in your model object, you have to define constructors in your model classes like that :

```
constructor(obj?: any) {
    Object.assign(this, obj);
}
```

Then in your services add a mapping like this :

```
http.get<MyClass>('/my-class').pipe(
      map(res => new MyClass(res))
```

Note: the code above is RxJS 6 style, i don't know which version you are using

Comment: Thanks to you I reread [this tutorial](https://nehalist.io/working-with-models-in-angular/) that I did not do to the end.
What I now do in the service is this: `return stuffObjects.map(stuff => new MyClass().deserialize(stuff));

Comment: You're welcome, I personnally like the constructor way, the `Deserialize` interface is another suitable option

Comment: this will only work when `MyClass` does not have complex members (eg members of type `Date` or other classes)

Comment: @Jota.Toledo yes, and this can be solved by defining setters for those properties

Comment: thanks very helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014161/angular2-http-get-cast-response-into-full-object

Answer (score -2):

It works for me like this

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

...
this.httpClient.get<MyResponse>('http://......').toPromise()
      .then((myResponse) => {
        console.log('myResponse.myField: ' + JSON.stringify(tokenResponse));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Promise rejected with ' + JSON.stringify(error));
      });

...
interface MyResponse {
  myField: string;
  myOtherField: string;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Please read the question again, it's about calling functions on a business class hydrated from the backend, how an interface solves this problem?

Comment: @GuerricP this question is about deserializing server response into a model and this is exactly what my code does.