# Array of Elements doesn't get populated by an interface

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

I make following request in Angular and save the response in a variable:

```
conversations: Conversation[];

// ChatService
getConversations() {
    return this.http.get<Conversation[]>('/chat/conversations');
}

this.chatService.getConversations().subscribe(
    (response: Conversation[]) => this.conversations = response
);
```

This is the JSON Data from the Server:

```
[  
   {  
      "chatRoomId":"096b8be1-2411-4cb1-94e0-ed96c51c23d8",
      "name":"Bar",
      "profilePicture":"...",
      "conversation":[  
         {  
            "name":"Bar",
            "message":"Hello!",
            "createdAt":"2018-09-30T06:50:49.000+0000"
         },
         {  
            "name":"Foo",
            "message":"Hi",
            "createdAt":"2018-09-30T11:49:05.000+0000"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

TypeScript Models:

```
export interface Conversation {
  chatRoomId: string;
  name: string;
  profilePicture: string;
  conversation: ChatMessage[]
}

export interface ChatMessage {
  name: string;
  message: string;
  createdAt: string;
}
```

**The problem:**

If i output the variable in the console, the conversation (`conversation: ChatMessage[]`) is an empty array element.

And if i make the request with `this.http.get<any>('...')`, the conversation get's stored as expected.

Comment: do you have changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush in your template code?

Comment: Which variable do you output in the console ?

Comment: @Radik Yes, the data i receive gets saved in a BehaviorSubject to which i subscribe.

Comment: @billyjov For debug purposes the variable conversations.

Comment: What appened if you use a response with type `any` ?

Comment: @billyjov Then everything work's as expected, but i want to use an interface for it.

Comment: then try `this.conversations = response.data` instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181023/discussion-between-billyjov-and-prolativ).

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways you can do what you're trying to do but from my experience, using this library has been the easiest: https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer

Here's how it would work in your situation. First I would change your interfaces to be Typescript Classes.

```
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';

export class Conversation {
    chatRoomId: string;
    name: string;
    profilePicture: string;

    @Type(() => ChatMessage)
    conversation: ChatMessage[]

    constructor(args: Conversation) {
      Object.assign(this, args);
    }
}

export class ChatMessage {
    name: string;
    message: string;
    createdAt: string;

    constructor(args: ChatMessage) {
      Object.assign(this, args);
    }
}
```

A few things changed from when these were interfaces::

1. The use of the `@Type` decorator comes from the class-transformer module. This allows you to transform nested objects. Here is the documentation: https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#working-with-nested-objects
2. We've added a `constructor` which allows you to create instances of these Classes and pass through attributes to them of their own respective types. Take a look at this post [Converting httpClient answer to model objects [Angular 6]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50551649/converting-httpclient-answer-to-model-objects-angular-6) as it shines more light onto whats happening here.

Then within your service this is how your code changes:

```
import { plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';    

conversations: Conversation[];

// ChatService
getConversations() {
    return this.http.get<Conversation[]>('/chat/conversations');
}

this.chatService.getConversations().subscribe(
    (response: Conversation[]) => {
        this.conversations = plainToClass(Conversation, response) as Conversation[]
    }
);
```

`plainToClass` will take the raw JSON response and transform it into instances of your Conversation Class. If you console.log out `this.conversations` you will see that it returns an Array of Conversations that each have an array attribute called `conversations` of type ChatMessage.

Comment: this post is utterly misleading. nothing of the stated meets the issue. interfaces do not do anything at runtime (they dont even exist at runtime to be exact) - and changing the type to any will not change the runtime experience - ever.
You are speaking of TypeScript checking the JSON response, but TypeScript doesn't do anything at runtime, it is a transpiler.

Comment: @PatrickKelleter How does this look now? You are right, typescript doesn't do any runtime type checking that's my bad. Using Javascript classes here is what I would do, since it allows you to organize the service response json and clearly define nested classes.

Comment: I can not say that using classes is wrong by any mean - but i can say that i actually prefer interfaces over classes whenever possible. there are plenty of reasons for that - too many for this comment - but the most important one is that i dislike the idea of oop (just as many others do nowadays)
for typesafety it is easier and less verbose to use interfaces over classes, so if you do not oop you may just use interfaces in 90% of the time instead. there are definitely use cases for classes, but i would say they are about 10% compared to interfaces

Comment: btw it is worth mentioning that i used classes a lot in the beginning (typescript 1.1 is when i started using it) since i came from java and was used to that design pattern. but over the time i replaced more and more of my code by interfaces and type definitions. the code turns out to be much leaner if you stick to that paradigm. actually there are plenty of blog posts comparing class/interface/type, you may just give it a shot at google.
also the typescript docs are very insightful, personally I learned a lot from that source and, as mentioned, blog posts.