# Angular 8: is not a function, how to fix

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I wrote a function in a class which returns data, When calling this from another component, receiving error below, the other class members show up in debugger, but it cannot recognize the function.

Getting error

> TypeError: this.addressTestData.getValidateAddressLine is not a function

```
public addressTestData: AddressMailingData = new AddressMailingData();

validateaddress = this.addressTestData.getValidateAddressLine();
```

Comment: How are you creating this `validateAddressRequest` object?

Comment: Stop doing such destructive comment-pastes. Edit your question, take some time to make it right, than save changes and wait for help.

Comment: Can you share where validateAddress() is called?

Comment: @SailorLuvBoat This is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50551649/483655

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.addressTestData` is not of type `AddressMailingData`

Your debug screen shows it is just an `OBJECT`

Comment: That does not matter how you declared it. In Typescript there is no runtime type controll so it can be anyting - even plain javascript object.

Comment: You need to create that object with `new` keyword so it will be indeed an instance of given class.

Comment: No idea, you didnt show code for instance creation.

Comment: No code - hard to help. Anyway answer is valid - its of different type

Comment: I checked out this link, and it worked, thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997765/reactive-forms-correctly-convert-form-value-to-model-object

Answer (score 1):

@SailorLuvBoat: Yes, as per your comment, the problem lies with the assumption that `currentMessage` is an `AddressMailingData` instance - it isn't!

It is a plain javascript object, with (probably) all the same properties as `AddressMailingData`, but without any of the methods.

You will need to instantiate a new `AddressMailingData` object, then copy all of the property values from `currentMessage` into it.  You could use the javascript method [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to do this simply.

You could change your AddressMailingData constructor to this:

```
export class AddressMailingData {
    constructor(data?: any) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
```

And then your subscription handler to this:

```
this.addressMailingStandardService.currentMessage.subscribe(currentMessage => { 
  this.addressStandardMessage = new AddressMailingData(currentMessage);
  ...
});
```

Then `this.addressStandardMessage` will contain a valid `AddressMailingData` instance, and you will be able to access your `.getValidateAddressLine()` method.