# Angular: Convert API Data into New Data Type in Reusable/Clean Method

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular10

I am trying to convert an API Response into a totally different ViewModel, for multiple components.

a) One solution is to map/pipe the Data directly in the API proxy, however then API proxy is not very reusable, if I just want plain raw API Data.

b) This model-adapter pattern may not work, since in the example the adapter creates the same Data Object Type as API. https://florimond.dev/blog/articles/2018/09/consuming-apis-in-angular-the-model-adapter-pattern/ .
Our data converter below, brings out totally different one.

Looking for any other good solutions.

**Regular API:**

```
export class ProductService {
  private readonly apiUrl = environment.baseUrl + '/api/CalculateProducts/';
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getProductData(
    productValuationDtoRequest: ProductValuationDtoRequest
  ): Observable<ProductValuationResponse>  {
    return this.httpClient.request<ProductValuationResponse>('post', this.apiUrl,
      {body: productValuationDtoRequest}
    );
  }
}
```

**Data Converter:**

```
export class CalculateProductModelService {
  constructor() { }

  convertData(
    productValuationResponse: ProductValuationResponse): CalculateCostModel  {

    const calculateProductModel: CalculateProductModel = {
      valuationAttribute: productValuationResponse?.productValuationDetail[0]?.productValuationAttribute?.description,
      livingAreaQuantity: productValuationResponse?.productValuationDetail[0]?.quantity,
      livingAreaRate: productValuationResponse?.productValuationDetail[0]?.improvementUnitValue * 1.03,
      livingAreaValue: productValuationResponse?.productValuationDetail[0]?.attributeTotalImprovementValue,
      numberOfUnits: productValuationResponse?.numberOfUnits * 2,
      replacementCostNew: productValuationResponse?.replacementCostNew,
      goodPercentage: productValuationResponse?.percentageGood,
      goodValue: productValuationResponse?.replacementCostNew * (100 - productValuationDto?.percentageGood) / 100,
      total: productValuationResponse?.totalImprovementValue
    };
    return calculateProductModel;
  }
```

Comment: You should start accepting answers for your questions or at least leave a comment to the answers you think are not acceptable.

Answer (score 8):

If I understand the problem right, I would add a method to `ProductService` to return the Model, so that `ProductService` ends up having 2 methods, one for the raw API data and one for the model.

The new method would internally use the current `getProductData` method to fetch the data and the `CalculateProductModelService` to perform the transformation.

The code would look like

```
export class ProductService {
  private readonly apiUrl = environment.baseUrl + '/api/CalculateProducts/';
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, 
     private productModelService: CalculateProductModelService) { }

  getProductData(
    productValuationDtoRequest: ProductValuationDtoRequest
  ): Observable<ProductValuationResponse>  {
    return this.httpClient.request<ProductValuationResponse>('post', this.apiUrl,
      {body: productValuationDtoRequest}
    );
  }

  getProductModel(
    productValuationDtoRequest: ProductValuationDtoRequest
  ): Observable<CalculateProductModel>  {
    return this.getProductData(productValuationDtoRequest).pipe(
      map(rawData => productModelService.convertData(rawData))
    );
  }
}
```

In the above example I use Dependency Injection to inject `CalculateProductModelService` into `ProductService`. In this way `CalculateProductModelService` is not dependent on http calls and can be easily tested.